# If $I'$ is bounded, then the mapping $u \mapsto d(u,A) + d(u,B)$ is bounded below

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, calculus-of-variations

So I was reading the Deformation Theorem of Chapter 8.5 of "Partial Differential Equations" by Evans, and I'm confused about one step of the proof.

First, some definitions. $H$ is a real Hilbert space with norm $||\cdot||$ and inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$. Also, $I:H \to \mathbb{R}$ is a nonlinear functional.

> **DEFINITION.** We say $I$ is differentiable at $u \in H$ if there exists $v \in H$ such that
> $$I[w]=I[u]+(v,w-u)+o(||w-u||) \quad (w \in H)$$
> The element $v$, if it exists, is unique. We then write $I'[u]=v$.

> **DEFINITION.** We say $I$ belongs to $C^1(H;\mathbb{R})$ if $I'[u]$ exists for each $u \in H$ and the mapping $I':H \to H$ is continuous.

We also write $\mathcal{C}$ to represent the collection of functions $I \in C^1(H;\mathbb{R})$ such that $I':H \to H$ is Lipschitz continuous on bounded subsets of $H$.

Now, suppose $I \in \mathcal{C}$, $0<\delta<\epsilon$, and define the sets

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& A:=\{u \in H \mid I[u] \leq c-\epsilon \text { or } I[u] \geq c+\epsilon\}, \\
& B:=\{u \in H \mid c-\delta \leq I[u] \leq c+\delta\} .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

The claim is

> Since $I'$ is bounded on bounded sets, we verify that the mapping $u \mapsto dist(u,A) +dist(u,B)$ is bounded below by a positive constant on each bounded subset of $H$.

Here's the proof that I came up with:

Suppose by contradiction that there exists $u_o \in H$ such that $dist(u_0,A)+dist(u_0,B)=0$. Thus, $dist(u_0,A)=0$ and $dist(u_0,B)=0$, which is equivalent to $u_0 \in \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}$ (where the bar represents the closure).

Now, let $v \in \bar{B}$. Then there exists a sequence $v_n \in A$ such that $v_n \to v$ in H. Since $I$ is continuous, $I[v_n] \to I[v]$, and thus $c-\delta \leq I[v] \leq c+ \delta$, so $v \in B$, thus $B=\bar{B}$ is closed.

By a similar reasoning, we get that $A=\bar{A}$ is closed. so $u_0 \in \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}= A \cap B = \emptyset$, a contradiction.

So I have some doubts about this "proof", since I never used the hypothesis that $I'$ is bounded on bounded sets, although I can't see the error in it. Could someone point out my mistake? Is it because $u_0$ in the conditions above may not exist? I am also aware of a correct way to prove this, as can be seen in [On the proof of deformation lemma "boundedness"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452507/on-the-proof-of-deformation-lemma-boundedness), but I'd like to know if my reasoning can be salvaged.

Comment: $I:H\to H$ should be $I:H\to\Bbb R.$

Comment: I didn't read the sequel but your proof has a flaw at the very beginning, when you "Suppose by contradiction that there exists $u_0\in H$ such that $dist(u_0,A)+dist(u_0,B)=0$". The inf of the map might be $0$ without being attained.